# how to manually restart or stop virtuoso from commandline

Tags: debian, systemd, virtuoso, init.d, service-management

I have a new installed Virtuoso (from github > 7.2.4) on a `Debian jessie` system. <strike>It starts properly after boot.</strike>

How to stop, start, and restart manually the virtuoso web server? <strike>It starts after reboot.</strike> How can this be achieved from the command line?

<strike>How is the automatic restart after boot done? Does it use `/etc/init.d/` or `systemd`?</strike>

I cannot find files, neither in `systemd` nor in `service`? it seems possible to enable in `systemd` (on a different `Debian stretch` box), but not on `Debian jessie`.

thank you for help!

Comment: error - i just observed that the virtuoso server does not automatically start after reboot. how to set this properly?

Comment: Your questions do not seem specific to Virtuoso, but rather to service management on `debian jessie`. (Virtuoso does not automatically handle such on Linux, as there are multiple service managers, among other host-to-host variations.) [This page](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSIndex#Download,%20Build,%20and%20Use%20--%20Get%20Started!) seems likely to be of use.

Comment: @TallTed The page you link to does not even contain the words "restart" or "stop".

Comment: @WouterBeek I stand by my comments that this question is less about Virtuoso, and more about service management on Debian Jessie. Our [page about the Virtuoso package for Debian](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDebianNotes) doesn't discuss service management, because it's not part of what we provide. (ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Comment: I know how to start/stop services, so that's not the problem. For virtuoso7, it seems it is not used as a standard service. At least I cannot find it. So I am just as baffled as @user855443.

To be a bit more specific:

* how to find the virtuoso7 service?
* how to restart it?
Some background knowledge on my use case. I am profiling the server and try to optimize the performance. For that I change the config (the .ini file) and after that virtuoso needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 4):

I found a usable solution for my use case in a [message on the `virtuoso-users` mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/virtuoso-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00324.html)

```
isql 1111
shutdown();
```

This shuts down Virtuoso after which you can start it again via `virtuoso-t`

Comment: Note that this will only succeed if Virtuoso is running with default `dba` credentials, which is not recommended. An easy oneliner with credential placeholders is `isql {host}:{port} {UID} {PWD} EXEC=shutdown`, e.g., `isql localhost:1111 dbauid dbapwd EXEC=shutdown`.

Comment: You may need to use `isql-vt` or `isqlw-vt` in place of `isql` for later versions of Virtuoso.